# Integer rounding in C++

Tags: c++, int, cmath

I was trying to use the formula below in c++.  I have both variables declared as integers and I'm expecting them to round up but they seem to be rounding down.  I have looked over this but cannot seem to find what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int user_degrees_latitude, user_degrees_longitude;
const int lat_const=(-90)
const int long_const=(-180)

sector_latitude = (user_degrees_latitude - lat_const) / (10);
sector_longitude = (user_degrees_longitude - long_const) / (10);
```

The answer should be 13 for sector_latitude and 11 for sector_longitude but the computer rounds each down to 12 and 10 respectively.

Comment: Integers in C++ automatically "round down": 12.9 -> 12, if you want real rounding there is a `round()` function that takes `double`

Comment: Integers are truncated; they do not round

Comment: You're using unassigned variables, that's undefined behavior.  Thank your compiler for not erasing your disk.

Comment: The rounding of negative numbers used to be machine dependent.  Someone told me the newer C++ standards have changed this.

Answer (score 11):

In C++, integers are not rounded. Instead, integer division truncates (read: always rounds towards zero) the remainder of the division.

If you want to get a rounding effect for **positive** integers, you could write:

```
sector_latitude = static_cast<int>(((user_degrees_latitude - lat_const) / (10.0)) + 0.5);
```

The addition of 0.5 causes the truncation to produce a rounding effect. Note the addition of the `.0` on `10.0` to force a floating point divide before the addition.

I also assumed that `sector_latitude` was an int with the casting.

Comment: Very true. I was trying to give a simple definition for truncation, and I believe I oversimplified. Editing to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: What does the static_cast do since the variables are already integers?

Comment: the division by `10.0` promotes the result to a floating point (well, actually a double, I believe) number. The addition of `0.5` is now a floating point operation. The `static_cast<int>` forces the return to an integer type, which truncates the result of the floating point operation.

Comment: That is actually not correct for negative values. For example
(10-17)/10.0 == -0.7 which should be rounded to -1, but
static_cast<int>((10-17)/10.0 + 0.5) == 0

Comment: Thanks @Malloc. I edited again to reflect this. For the general case, i think your answer below is best.

Comment: This isn't truncation. See my comment on Baum mit Augen's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Although this thread is very old, I am saddened to see both existing answers converting to floating point then back to integer.  If you want to divide `n` by `d` and round the quotient to the nearest integer, all using integer-only arithmetic, then you simply add `d/2` before dividing:

```
q = (n + d/2) / d
```

(Of course, `d/2` could be written `d>>1`, but the compiler will do that for you.) So, if `n` is 19 and `d` is 4, the exact quotient would be 4.75, `n/d` would yield 4 (truncation towards zero), but the formula above would yield 5, which is the desired result.  For the example given in the OP, simply update the last two lines as follows:

```
sector_latitude = (user_degrees_latitude - lat_const + 5) / (10);
sector_longitude = (user_degrees_longitude - long_const + 5) / (10);
```

EDIT: It was pointed out (thanks, @kees-jan), that this solution won't work if `n` if `n` and `d` have different signs, thus yielding a negative quotient.  Below is a more complete solution that still avoids the expensive int-float-int conversion:

```
constexpr int div_round(int n, int d)
{
    int offset = (((n < 0) == (d < 0)) ? d : -d) / 2;
    return (n + offset) / d;
}

sector_latitude = div_round(user_degrees_latitude - lat_const, 10);
sector_longitude = div_round(user_degrees_longitude - long_const, 10);
```

Comment: That would not work for negative values of n, though...

Comment: @Kees-Jan: You are correct.  More accurately, it does not work if `n` and `d` have different signs. In fact, I ran into this exact issue in my own project.  I will amend my answer.  The principle is the same, though: don't convert to/from float when you can do everything with integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Integer division in C++ always rounds towards zero. Use floating-point division to get "exact" results and use `std::round` to round according to the normal rules:

```
sector_latitude = static_cast</*type of sector_latitude*/>( std::round( (user_degrees_latitude - lat_const) / 10.0 ));
```

The "10.0" (a `double`) instead of "10" (an `int`) tells the compiler to use floating-point arithmetic. It always chooses floating-point over integer calculation if a floating-point value like a `double` is involved.

Comment: `std::round()` will not return an integer type. Instead, it will return the same type (`float`, `double`, or `long double`) that was passed in. If `sector_latitude` is an integer type, an additional cast should be added.

Comment: It doesn't round at all. It truncates.

Comment: @EJP I know, but I believe "rounding towards zero" (which is what truncating does) is more helpful to OP than the term "truncating".

Comment: @user207421: it doesn't truncate. Remember that negative integers are stored as 2s complement. Truncating 2s complement gives *round down*, not round towards zero. As such, round towards zero is the correct description, and truncating is incorrect. I understand that most people aren't thinking about the underlying representation of the int, but given that it is 2s complement, the use of "truncation" is, at best, ambiguous.